# Properly reversing a string in C++ using strrev

Tags: c++, arrays, output

I would like the user to enter the string for strrev to reverse however when the user enters the string spaces are not allowed for some reason so if someone enters hello my name is stan. the output is only nats, How can i get the function to accept white space?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[] = "This is a c-StyleString";
    //cout <<"Enter the string:" << endl;
    //cin >> str;
    cout << "Reverse of the given string is: " << strrev(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strrev` is a deprecated function, which was only available in Microsoft toolchain and should not be used. You can reverse string with `std::reverse`.

Comment: i'm only asking for help because it is a school assignment which Requires the use of  strrev and no other way

Comment: @Beeeee, I (seriously, no kidding!) suggest you change schools before it's too late.