# 'strrev' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c-strings

Upon compiling I get "strrev was not declared in this code", it seems like I can not use strrev inside strcpy? If so, will assigning a char array the value of strrev(b) solve it? this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

ifstream fin("palindrom.in");
ofstream fout("palindrom.out");

int main(){
    int i, n = 0, x, v[100], q=0;
    char a[256], b[256], rev[256], be[256];
    
    int ind=0;
    fin>>x;

    fin.get();
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        fin.get(a, 256);
        fin.get();

        for(int j = 0; j < strlen(a); j++){
            if(!strchr(" ", a[j])){
                b[n++] = a[j];
            }
        }
        b[n++] = 0;
        strcpy(be, b);
        strcpy(rev, strrev(b));

        if(strcmp(be, rev) == 0){
            v[ind++] = 1;
        }
        else{
            v[ind++] = 0;
        }

        memset(b, 0, 256);
        n = 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
        fout<<v[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Here's where the error occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cdHd.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696323/properly-reversing-a-string-in-c-using-strrev ?

Comment: There are no `strrev` function in the standard library. If you want to reverse a container (even a C-style null-terminated (but not literal) string) use [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)